# returning bool masks with modulo operator for numpy arrays with excluding zeros

Tags: python, numpy

Hard to write down a title but pretty straight forward to explain. Having a `numpy array`:

```
arr1 = np.array([0,1,256,110,0,256,128,512])
```

I'd like to apply modulo 256 and return `True` masks for multiples of 256. `arr2 = arr1%256 == 0` doesn't works since 0's are also returning 0 with modulo thus interfering with actual zeros of division by 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
np.logical_and(arr1 % 256 == 0 , arr1 // 256 > 0)
```

OR

```
np.logical_and(arr1 % 256 == 0, arr1 != 0)
```

Output:

```
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```